# Automation to check if the email is opened or clicked

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

How do I check and assign 'Yes' value to the 'open' and 'clicked' row in my DE that I retrieved in _sent data view.

This is my current code:

```
       select 
j.JourneyName, 
j.VersionNumber, 
ja.ActivityName as 'EmailName', 
s.EventDate as 'SendTime', 
su.EmailAddress, 
su.SubscriberKey as 'ContactKey', 
s.SubscriberID as 'ContactID'    , 
s.JobID, 
s.ListID, 
s.BatchID 
from [_Sent] s 
join [_JourneyActivity] ja  
on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID 
join [_Journey] j 
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID 
join [_Subscribers] su 
on s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID 

left join [_open] o
on s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
left join [_click] c
on s.JobID = c.JobID and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1

where ja.ActivityType in  ('EMAIL','EMAILV2')
```

Comment: You could use a GROUP BY Clause and then a CASE on MAX(IsUnique), but this is a very expensive query with many joins. Do you have to do this in a single query? I'd consider breaking down into three less expensive queries - get sent, get opened and then get clicked.

Comment: I have built that same query - it will work, and it will fail once you have bigger sendouts due to timeouts. As Macca says, break it up into several sequential queries either now, or when you start debugging :) Then join the individual query results at the end.
To assign your value, simply get all Subscribers from e.g. _Click, and assign a static value in single quotes to your field of choice - SELECT Subscriberkey, 'yes' AS clicked FROM _Click.

Answer (score 0):

As @Macca has highlighted using multiple joins is very expensive and might run into time out issue. So split the query and use it. If you still want to use it then you can use the below code:

1st Query to get the Open date and Click Date as well along with other data.

2nd Query is to have a boolean field  "Is Opened" and "Is Clicked" and use Case statement to set the field values based on open date & click date.

```
select 
j.JourneyName, 
j.VersionNumber, 
ja.ActivityName as 'EmailName', 
s.EventDate as 'SendTime', 
su.EmailAddress, 
su.SubscriberKey as 'ContactKey', 
s.SubscriberID as 'ContactID'    , 
s.JobID, 
s.ListID, 
s.BatchID 
o.EventDate as Opendate
c.EventDate as Clickdate
from [_Sent] s 
join [_JourneyActivity] ja  
on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID 
join [_Journey] j 
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID 
join [_Subscribers] su 
on s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID 

left join [_open] o
on s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
left join [_click] c
on s.JobID = c.JobID and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1

where ja.ActivityType in  ('EMAIL','EMAILV2')
```

2nd Query will return you a Boolean value based on Open date and click date:

```
Select 
F.JourneyName, 
F.VersionNumber, 
F.EmailName, 
F.SendTime, 
F.EmailAddress, 
F.ContactKey, 
F.ContactID, 
F.JobID, 
F.ListID, 
F.BatchID,
F.Opendate,
F.Clickdate,
Case when F.OpenDate IS NULL  then 0 Else 1 End as [Is Opened],
Case when F.ClickDate IS NULL then 0 Else 1 End as [Is Clicked]
from first_query_DE as F
```

Let me know if this helps.